# GROUP BY to flatten each group member in a separate column

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am trying to generate a report in SSRS.

I have 2 tables as below:

**Address** table:

```
AddressId | AddressLine
```

**AddressCountEachMonth**

```
ID | AddressId | Date | Count
```

For each date(Year-Month) there is an entry in AddressCountEachMonth table with the count value.

What I would like to do is to be able to query AddressCountEachMonth to output the result as below

For example If I provide a start date: 2014-01-01 and and date: 2014-05-01

Query result should be:

```
Address | 2016-01 | 2016-02 | 2016-03 | 2016-04 | 2016-05| 

x            5          1         0       2          4
y            2          3         4       0          2
...
...
```

is there any function in SQL Server that would help? I looked into STUFF but could not generate the result.

Comment: There are two techniques you could use here.  The first is [pivoting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx).  The second is to write a [cross tab query](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/creating-cross-tab-queries-and-pivot-tables-in-sql/).  Both will transpose data, stored in rows, to columns.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data in the table?

Comment: Agree with @DineshDB; posting sample data and expected output helps us help you.  Alternatively you can [read up on the techniques](https://destinationdata.wordpress.com/2016/07/21/switching-rows-and-columns/) I've recommended.  If you get stuck implementing these edit your question to include the code you have and detail the problems you ran into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily SSRS provides the ability to pivot dynamically so you will not have to hard code a query or build dynamic sql.  Check out this article that shows step by step how to do this.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157334%28v=sql.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Another good one:

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/reporting-services/advanced-matrix-reporting-techniques/